# I want to send the attributes of an object by email, with each attribute showing in a different line

Tags: python, object, attributes

Assume I have the following class, with each object of the class having 3 attributes:

```
class Class:
    def __init__ (self, attribute_1, attribute_2, attribute_3):
        self.attribute_1 = attribute_1
        self.attribute_2 = attribute_2
        self.attribute_3 = attribute_3
```

Assume I want to have 7 objects for the Class (one object for a different day of the week), with the following attributes:

```
object_1 = Class("attribute_1_1", "attribute_1_2", "attribute_1_3")
object_2 = Class("attribute_2_1", "attribute_2_2", "attribute_2_3")
object_3 = Class("attribute_3_1", "attribute_3_2", "attribute_3_3")
object_4 = Class("attribute_4_1", "attribute_4_2", "attribute_4_3")
object_5 = Class("attribute_5_1", "attribute_5_2", "attribute_5_3")
object_6 = Class("attribute_6_1", "attribute_6_2", "attribute_6_3")
object_7 = Class("attribute_7_1", "attribute_7_2", "attribute_7_3")
```

Assume I want to create a function that sends me by email the attributes of a given object, and the object will be chosen depending on the day of the week we are in.

To automate which object to choose, first I would first define the variable x as the weekday:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
x = dt.weekday()
```

Then, to decide which object to choose today, I would do this. First, create the list of the 7 objects. Second, choosing the object of the list by using the defined variable x (which is the name of the week)

```
weekly_object=[object_1, object_2, object_3, object_4, object_5, object_6, object_7]
today_object=weekly_object[x]
```

Finally, I would like to send me the attributes of today_object over email. **I would like each attribute to be sent in a different line, and  Here is where I have the problem: I am getting the attributes in the same line**

```
import smtplib
import ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage

email_sender = 'xxxxxxx'
email_password = 'aaaaaaaaa'
email_receiver = 'eeeeeee'

subject = 'subject'
body = str(vars(today_object))
```

This is what I get in my email:

```
{'attribute_1': 'attribute_6_1', 'attribute_2': 'attribute_6_2', 'attribute_3': 'attribute_6_3'}
```

And this is what I would like to get

```
{'attribute_1': 'attribute_6_1' 
'attribute_2': 'attribute_6_2', 
'attribute_3': 'attribute_6_3'}
```

Any solution?

Comment: you have format it on your own using `for`-loop. Eventually convert to string and replace`,` with `,\n` - `text = text.replace( "," , ",\n" )`

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert to string and later replace `,` with `,\n`

```
data = {'attribute_1': 'attribute_6_1', 'attribute_2': 'attribute_6_2', 'attribute_3': 'attribute_6_3'}

text = str(data)
print(text)

text = text.replace(',', ',\n')
print(text)
```

Result:

```
{'attribute_1': 'attribute_6_1', 'attribute_2': 'attribute_6_2', 'attribute_3': 'attribute_6_3'}

{'attribute_1': 'attribute_6_1',
 'attribute_2': 'attribute_6_2',
 'attribute_3': 'attribute_6_3'}
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also try to convert to JSON (but not all type of data can be converted this way)

```
data = {'attribute_1': 'attribute_6_1', 'attribute_2': 'attribute_6_2', 'attribute_3': 'attribute_6_3'}

import json

text = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
print(text)
```

Result:

```
{
  "attribute_1": "attribute_6_1",
  "attribute_2": "attribute_6_2",
  "attribute_3": "attribute_6_3"
}
```

---

You can also use `for`-loop and format it on your own.
This allows to make more changes ie. `=>` instead of `:`

```
data = {'attribute_1': 'attribute_6_1', 'attribute_2': 'attribute_6_2', 'attribute_3': 'attribute_6_3'}

text = '{\n'

for key, value in data.items():
    text += f"  {key} => {value},\n"
    
text += '}'

print(text)
```

Result:

```
{
  attribute_1 => attribute_6_1,
  attribute_2 => attribute_6_2,
  attribute_3 => attribute_6_3,
}
```